# Deletion of a Post

Tags: support

How do you mark a post for deletion? I cannot see delete any were?

E.g. This post may need deletion as it is always coming up as the 1st post when I refresh the quesion: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/how-can-i-determine-if-someone-has-remotely-accessed-my-phone-or-if-it-has-been

I reported this a few hours ago but a few hours later it still is hanging out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How can a post be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/139866)

The post you linked to was flagged (for moderator attention), and was downvoted; but no-one had yet voted to close it (so it wasn't on track towards being deleted).

To delete a closed question, the system wants three high-reputation users (or one moderator) to vote to delete.

---

> I reported this a few hours ago...

Flags are only seen by the moderators of *this* site (they're not seen by all 400+ SE moderators), and that can only happens when a moderator is awake and reading the site. That tends to happen every day but not every hour, so don't be alarmed if something flagged takes many hours to be processed.

Taking fairly immediate action might be one of the reasons why [SE would like the community to act](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1873/254) instead of only depending on moderators.

Comment: Also perhaps escalate this to SE for further investigation if appropriate.